# Не понимаю почему нужен второй конструктор?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Я новичек в C++, прошу подсказать, почему возникает ошибка если не определить 2 конструктор в следующем коде, можно ли как-то избежать определения второго конструктора?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

class Int
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    Int(): a(0) {}


void shownumber()
{
    std::cout << a;
}

void setnumber(int number)
{
    a = number;
}

Int calculate(Int number)
{
    return a + number.a;
}
```

};

```
int main()
{   
    Int x, y, z;
    x.setnumber(123);
    y.setnumber(77);
    z = x.calculate(y);
    z.shownumber();

return 0;
```

}

Прошу подсказать.

Comment: при добавлении второго конструктора вида Int(int x): a(x) {}

Comment: Потому что вы пытаетесь вызвать этот конструктор возвращая экземпляр класса `Int` созавая его из числа `int` в `return a + number.a;` Вызова этого конструктора можно избежать записав `Int x; x.a = a + number.a; return x;`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: а как понять что конструктор вызывается?

Comment: Конструктор вызывается, когда создается объект. Этот метод возвращает `Int`  - значит в `return` будет вызван конструктор результата.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение.